# What is the difference between Fluent UI People Picker and Pnp Spfx React PeoplePicker

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, pnp, fluent-ui

I am using [PnP SPFx React PeoplePicker](https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/PeoplePicker/) in one of my SPFx web part, it works fine. But later I found out that MS Fluent UI also have a [PeoplePicker](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/peoplepicker). Going through the [docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/peoplepicker) it seems a little bit different than PnP PeoplePicker by looking at the implementation.

I just want to know if there are some major differences or if one is having advantage over other so I can consider in my future work and suggest to my team.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of below advantages of using PnP SPFx PeoplePicker control:

1. You can limit the people results to specific SharePoint group just by passing the group name as a property to PeoplePicker control like:

   ```
   <PeoplePicker
      groupName={"Team Site Owners"} // Leave this blank in case you want to filter from all users

      context={this.props.context}
      titleText="People Picker"
      required={true}
      onChange={this._getPeoplePickerItems}
      principalTypes={[PrincipalType.User]}
   />
   ```
2. You can define which type of data you want to retrieve: User, SharePoint groups, Security groups just by passing values in `principalTypes` (Multiple are possible).
3. PnP SPFx PeoplePicker provides out of the box `required` validation (Not sure if it is available in Fluent UI - need to check)

It's always better to look at the configuration options provided by the control & match them with your requirements while deciding which one to use in your solution.